# Adding aliases for macro annotations

Tags: scala, annotations, alias, scala-macros

While doing DSL stuff, I'd like to **add several aliases to an existing macro annotation** and, if possible, I'd like to avoid typing the `macroTransform` definition. That is to say that I want to declare an alias for the "macro header", instead of the macro implementation.

I've been doing some unsuccessful attempts. For instance, given the original annotation header,

```
class original extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*) = macro originalImpl
}
```

I tried to make an alias by using a type alias:

```
type alias1 = original
@alias1 trait Whatever
```

Besides, I deployed an inheriting annotation version:

```
class alias2 extends original
@alias2 trait Whatever
```

However, **none of them expand**. Is there any convenient way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far that's impossible, because the typechecker uses a very restricted name resolution algorithm to figure out whether a given identifier refers to a macro annotation. Within the restrictions of this algorithm, it's unfortunately impossible to dealias. I've created a bug report at https://github.com/scalamacros/paradise/issues/8.